# How to craft a regex for processing a source file, where the search pattern is built from function name?

Tags: c, regex, bash, sed

I need to write a script to process millions of lines of code spread out over thousands of c files. Part of what I need to accomplish is a search and replace where the search string is built from name of the function it is in. What tools could I use to automate this? I think I could write a bash script that crafts a new sed command for every function contained in a file, but I don't know how to programmatically identify functions without recreating the wheel.

Example function

```
void foo123()
{
    printf("foo123: hello world");
}
```

So I want to search for the pattern `printf("FUNCTION_NAME:` and then replace it. There are thousands of these functions.

Comment: Something like ctags and/or cscope might be useful for "getting a list of functions by file". That said you might even be able to get gcc or clang to give you that (certainly objdump/etc. could for "public" functions in object files). That being said I'm not sure I understand the exact goal here. Can you explain with some examples?

Comment: Added an exmaple that hopefully helps a little

Comment: If you can construct a pattern (or set of patterns) that can correctly identify the intro to your functions and a pattern (or set of patterns) that can identify the lines that need replacing then it should be possible to do this fairly simply with an `awk` script.

Comment: I have written a Perl script do achieve the same kind of thinks. I used `astyle` (because I needed to be sure that each conditionnal had an opening curly brace), forced some rules such as new lines for each instruction. You can basically do the same thing, and read line by line. When you hit a function, store the name, count the curly braces (to identify when you get out) and if you have some printf with the name of the function you kept, you can change it!
By the way, gcc provides a `__FUNCTION__` macro.

Comment: Thanks both of you, will investigate astyle and awk as potential solutions.  BTW, the end purpose of this is to replace hard coded function name string literals with the gcc `__func__` macro. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [capturing-group](/questions/tagged/capturing-group) and [backreference](/questions/tagged/backreference):

```regex
([a-zA-Z]+ ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\(\)[[:space:]]+{[^}]+)printf("\2.+
```

Replace to:

```regex
\1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with:

I used ctags to create a list of functions and line numbers. Then for each function in the output, I used sed to do a substitution where the regex was formed partly by the function name.

I coded the above functionality up in a python script and used subprocess calls for running ctags and sed.  It took about a days work to get it running but it's doing the job.